# How can I loop through a new generated array without overwrite it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

I've been learning to code by my own so my knowledge isn't as technical as you'd expect it to be. Having saying that, I'm in a project that handles images and that includes showing information about them with the fileList object to the user, part of that information is shown in this format: **Chrysanthemum.jpg (image/jpeg) - 879394 bytes, last modified: 13/7/2009**. My program allows the user to delete preselected files before uploading the remaining ones, when that item is deleted from the group the information about it should go as well. I'm not going to make you go crazy reading +600 lines of code so you can tackle down my problem, therefore I'm giving you a very simple summarized approach of what my issue is.

in this case we want to deleted the first item when a function is called so take a peek to the next code:

```
<input type='button' id='load' value='Load_info' />
<div id='ok'>
    <ul id='pic_info'></ul>
</div>
<div id='message'></div>
<input type='button' id='bye' value='Bye[0]' />


var files = ["Chrysanthemum.jpg (image/jpeg) - 879394 bytes, last modified: 13/7/2009", "Desert.jpg (image/jpeg) - 845941 bytes, last modified: 13/7/2009", "Hydrangeas.jpg (image/jpeg) - 595284 bytes, last modified: 13/7/2009", "Jellyfish.jpg (image/jpeg) - 775702 bytes, last modified: 13/7/2009", "Koala.jpg (image/jpeg) - 780831 bytes, last modified: 13/7/2009", "Lighthouse.jpg (image/jpeg) - 561276 bytes, last modified: 13/7/2009", "Penguins.jpg (image/jpeg) - 777835 bytes, last modified: 13/7/2009"];

var once = 0;
var a = '';
var d = '';
//someFlag = true;
//var upd = [];
var e;
var f = '';
var g = 0;

function load() {
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        a += "<li>" + files[i] + "</li>";
        $("#pic_info").html(a);
        e = $("#pic_info li").length;
    }
}



function delete_item(arr, inx) {
    if (e <= 0) {
        e = 7;
    } else {
        e -= 1;
    }
    //for (var c = 0; c < arr.length; c++) {
      //  d += "<li>" + arr[c] + "</li>";
        //$("#pic_info").html(d);
    //}
    arr.splice(inx, 1);
    $("#pic_info").html(arr);
}

$("#load").click(function () {
    if (once == 0) {
        load();
        once = 1;
    } else {
        $("#message").html("<strong>files already loaded</strong>");
    }
});

$("#bye").click(function () {
    delete_item(files, 0);
});
```

I haven't been able to find an effective way to rearrange the "arr" items in "li" tags, I tried to loop through them but if you enable the "for loop" to happen the array itself it's overwritten with the new output till it reaches the last item. I've tried a bunch of stuff to fix this seemingly simple problem and I couldn't...... I gave up and decided to get help from people with a better formation

PD: I know there are a thousand plugins to handle files. I just wanna test some learned skills.

here it's a fiddle:
* [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ft49cjpr/)

Thanks for your time I really appreciate it and I hope I have explained myself

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure what your asking, but I believe your asking how to delete the first li element after you loaded the files.  Is that correct?

If so you can just use a jQuery selector, in your delete item and it will remove the first li but not affect the files array.

```
$("li").first().remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put new data with out overwrite the old data use `.append()` I can see you are using `.html()` this will set the html over the old one. Use `.append()` instead